# Spark fix task number for Spark SQL jobs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I keep seeing that Apache Spark schedules series of stages with a fixed 200 tasks involved. Since this keeps happening to a number of different jobs I am guessing this is somehow related to one of Spark configurations. Any suggestion what that configuration might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200 is a default number of partitions used during shuffles and it is controlled by `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. Its value can set on runtime using `SQLContext.setConf`:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "42")
```

or `RuntimeConfig.set`

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 42)
```

Comment: Thanks, going to try that. but is there a reason you suggesting 42? I was thinking about increasing the number.

Comment: Just because this is an answer to everything :) Seriously though this depends on your data and setup so I simply used the first number that comes to mind.

Comment: that solved the issue. I increased it to 512 in my case.