# Spark SQL Join: how it actually works

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I failed to figure out how actually Spark SQL join operation works. I have read [pretty massive explanation](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html), but it doesn't bring a light on few questions.

### Example

For example, you have two database tables which are saved in Spark (in parquet or any other format). And you have to join them based on some column:

```
SELECT t1.column_name_1 
FROM parquet.`data/table1.parquet` as t1 
LEFT JOIN parquet.`data/table2.parquet` as t2 
ON t2.column_name_2 = t1.column_name_1 
WHERE t2.column_name_2 is NULL 
LIMIT 1
```

I gonna launch this query as `sparkSession.sql(joinQuery)`

### Questions

1. *How Spark gonna shuffle `table1.parquet` RDD and `table2.parquet` RDD?* As I understand, Spark need some key, by which it perform shuffling. What would be the key if `column_name_1` & `column_name_2` each has 1.000.000 unique rows? How many unique keys (partitions) I will get? How many shuffles I will get?
2. *Is it possible to make Spark NOT fetch the whole `table1.parquet` and `table2.parquet` RDD into memory?*

### Why I suspicios about filtering

There is pretty trivial solution - just fiter DataFrames before filtering, and you will keep everything in RAM. But, I'm not sure this will perform well in my case.

Let's say filtering allow you to retrieve `table1_subset1` and `table1_subset2` from `table1`. Now to get the same join results u need to do more joins. I mean:

```
table1 JOIN table2 = table1_subset1 JOIN table2 + table1_subset2 JOIN table2
```

The same thing if I will filter `table2`:

```
table1 JOIN table2 = table1_subset1 JOIN table2_subset1 + table1_subset2 JOIN table2_subset1 +
                     table1_subset1 JOIN table2_subset2 + table1_subset2 JOIN table2_subset2
```

Now I have to join about 50 pairs of huge tables, each of them should be split into multiple chunks (subsets), lets say 5 chunks. So instead of `50 joins` I will get `50 * 5 * 5 = 1250` filter and join operations between chunks, where each of chunks is 5 times smaller that original table (RDD).

Am I right if I suppose that performance will downgrade a lot? Or Spark is clever enough to perform the same amount of shuffles?

Comment: What do you by "how"? And what else would you like to happen than reading all data?

Comment: @zero323 as I understand, Spark need some key, by which it perform shuffling. What would be the key if I have 1.000.000 unique values? How many unique keys (partitions) I will get?

Comment: @zero323 updated the question

Comment: You'll get as many partitions [as it is configured](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38851800/1560062). It doesn't depend on the number of keys. "Key" is an equi-join condition so it is not configurable. Finally Spark heavily utilizes the memory but it is not limited to "in-memory" and heavily depends on disk access for number of operations including shuffles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  You can choose between a shuffle sort join or a shuffle hash join by explicitly setting spark.shuffle.manager (default is sort).  A little more information is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html).  Hash is more efficient when you have a lot of keys in both tables.

2)  In order to get around this issue, you need to filter your data before getting to this point.  It's actually faster to add a prior step where you create a DataFrame(s) that represents the subset of data that you care about.  Spark will also spill to disk by default in case you can't fit your dataframe(s) into memory.  You can use saveAsTable() in the case of huge dataframes that consume all of your memory.

Comment: so if neither table1 nor table2 feets in memory,  than I need to filter each table multiple times.  I. E.  filter table1 N times,  and table2 M times.  Than I need to do NxM join operations

Comment: is there any other solution,  than filtering.  Filtering seems tremendously ineffective for me

Comment: how sort shuffle gonna shuffle 1.000.000 unique values?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Can you explain why you need to filter each table multiple times?  Also, can you please clarify your question re: how it's going to shuffle 1M unique values?  It uses a mergesort algorithm if that's what you're asking.  This is the recommended way, per [this DataBricks talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp53QhSfQcI&feature=youtu.be) at Spark Summit East 2017.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer. But I will upvote it, it definitelly shouldn't have -1.  I've also updated my first question relatively How it works. About the filtering - let's say filtering allow you to retrieve `table1_subset1` and `table1_subset2`. Now to get the same join results u need to do more joins. I mean  `table1 join table2 =  table1_subset1 join table2 + table1_subset2 join table2`. Am I right?

Comment: I have huge  tables that I need to split each in ~10 chunks. So I will get `10 x 10` joins for each pair of tables. Is Spark able not degradate performance on `10 x 10` filtering and joins instead one huge join?

Comment: Currently there isn't really a better way than filtering the dataframe(s) down to only include the rows you care about prior to the join.  Since you're outer joining, you might not even have that available.  Re: memory concerns, I've edited my answer to address that a bit further.